# Faking MS exchange whith php

Tags: php, synchronization, exchange-server

first post on stackoverflow!
We are developing a php contact manager.
We wanted to create the possibility to sync the contacts with ms exchange enabled phones (android, iphone, blackberry).
I found this link http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/exchange_webdav_examples.php#create_contact
but what I need is more on the sync side, not create, move etc.
Would be great to know what kind of data (xml, json), and how is formatted so I could fake the responses or parse the requests...
Any Idea?

Comment: I know Zimbra was forced to get a license or pay for the protocol for its exchange connector, and I'm sure they tried to backward engineer it. Best of luck though. If you can get it to work, please open source it so all the FOSS email applications can utilize it. I just hope it doesn't require an id key for the program  to be an approved connector program.

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [The Missing Sync](http://www.markspace.com/) for the backend, and front it :)